# Is there a way to store a key/value record somewhere so that it's accessible by several apps?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

Under Android, Is there a way to store a key/value record somewhere so that it's can be accessible by several app?

[image]

For example, under windows, we can store some stuff like this in the registry. Is there any equivalent under android ?

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. You are welcome to create your own `ContentProvider` and try to convince other developers to use it, but that's it.

Perhaps the Windows registry changed in the past couple of decades, but it used to be an insecure dumping ground that never got cleaned up properly.

Android avoids that sort of thing. The objective is that most (if not all) app data should be removed when the app is uninstalled. This sort of shared database can't be cleaned up very easily, as Android cannot readily know if another app needs values stored the app that is being uninstalled.